# Golaem add an entitytype python

Tags: python, maya

I was trying to create a script to add an entitytype from golaem in maya python but maya always returned me an error # Error: NameError: name 'glmCrowdEntityTypeNodeCmd' is not defined # please, any idea How Could I make it?

Any idea how to create it?

Answer (score 0):

`glmCrowdEntityTypeNodeCmd`is a mel command. You can try:

```
import pymel.core as pm
pm.mel.glmCrowdEntityTypeNodeCmd()
```

or

```
import maya.mel as mel
mel.eval("glmCrowdEntityTypeNodeCmd")
```